# Can I visit outside Incheon Airport with these conditions?

Tags: layovers, south-korea, filipino-citizens

1. I have a 17-hour layover for my CEB-AUH flight via Incheon
2. I am a Filipino holding an active Working/Resident visa in the United Arab Emirates valid until 2020
3. I have an active US Tourist Visa valid until 2028

Answer (score 2):

You aren’t visa free to South Korea. You can only transit without a visa if you stay in the departures area. You will need to apply for a visit visa to exit the airport.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, having a US visa allows you to exit Incheon airport during a transit, but only when you are traveling to or from the US.

Anecdotally, I have heard that Korean immigration officials have allowed transiting passengers with a US visa to leave the airport even if they are not traveling to or from the US. I would not count on this, though, as it is very likely a mistake.